# Redis hmget timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, redis

I'm matching a bunch of strings using `REDIS.hmget`. The full store has about ~140k keys. I've seen my backend match over 1k strings in less than 1s, but I came accross this particular case where the matching times out before finishing. I get the follow crash trace:

```
Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:58:in `write'
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:58:in `write'
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:139:in `process'
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:138:in `each'
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:138:in `process'
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:250:in `ensure_connected'
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:137:in `process'
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:206:in `logging'
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:136:in `process'
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis/client.rb:46:in `call'
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:755:in `hmget'
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/redis-2.2.2/lib/redis.rb:754:in `hmget'
```

Although it times out, hmget still returns what it has matched so far, which seems to vary between 2 and 2.3k strings. Like I said earlier, I've seen the backend match over 1k strings in less than 1 second, so I have a hard time to conceive that 2.3k strings makes Redis timeout, unless it times out only after a couple seconds.

Is there anything I might me missing here? Should I be breaking the match into 2 smaller ones? Is there a way to change the default timeout interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up splitting the lookup in small batches and haven't got the problem since. Something like:

```
BATCH_MATCHING_COUNT = 1000
values = Array.new
i = 0

while i < keys.length
    values.push(REDIS.hmget("hash", *keys[h, BATCH_MATCHING_COUNT]))
    i+=1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this question while working in the same issue but in PHP. I've found that casting the keys to string solved the issue. This is when you call Redis::hmGet(hash, keys) ; keys should be an array of STRING values. I had the same issue than you when at least one of the values was an integer.
Probably what you call "backend" does the cast to string, and your front-end does not. Give a look to that.

Comment: I confirm that `keys` is an array of strings. Also, if that was the issue, it would be reproducible, whereas now it just arbitrarily times out when there are over 1-2k keys.